# Getting error when modifying MyType constructed using typedef in C

Tags: c, struct, typedef

I create a type and try to change the int value in it.
But it keeps printing 240.
I don't know why, can anyone help me?
Here is my code:

```
typedef struct{
   int i;
}MyType;

do(MyType mt, int ii){
   mt.i = ii;
}

int main(int argc, char ** argv){
    MyType mt;
    do(mt, 5);
    print("%d\n", mt.i);
}
```

Comment: I'm honestly surprised that the code compiles.  `do` is a keyword in C.

Answer (score 3):

Passing `mt` by value to function `do()`. Any changes made will be local to the function. Pass the address of `mt`:

```
void do_func(MtType* mt, int ii){
    mt->i = ii;
}

MyType mt;
do_func(&mt, 5);
```

Answer (score 1):

So first, your `do` function has some problems.  You have failed to specify a return type, so int is assumed (pre-C99), but I see no reason to not just specify it.  Second, `do` is a reserved keyword in C.

You are passing your struct by value, so a copy is made, passed to your `do` function, and *that* is modified. Everything is passed by value in C, period.  Your `mt` variable declared in `main` is never touched.

Take a `MyType*` in your code if you need to modify one or more of its member variables, take a `MyType**` if you need to allocate memory for the structure itself (i.e., initialize a pointer).

```
// pass a pointer to the function to allow
// for changes to the member variables to be 
// visible to callers of your code.
void init_mytype(MyType *mt, int ii){
    if(mt)
        mt->i = ii;
}

MyType mt;
init_mytype(&mt, 1);

// pass a pointer to pointer to initialize memory
// for the structure and return a valid pointer.
// remember, everything is passed by value (copy)
void init_mytype(MyType **mt, int ii) {
    if(mt) {
        *mt = malloc(sizeof(MyType));
        if(*mt) 
            (*mt)->i = ii;
    }
}

MyType *pmt;
init_mytype(&pmt, 1);
```